# C# enter key leads to master page

Tags: c#, redirect, master-pages

I have a file named fiche.aspx which is tied to a master page.

In the master page there is a button click `calculete_somehing`.

When I pull up fiche.aspx and press enter on the keyboard, it runs the `calculete_somehing` method in the master page.

Why does that happen?

How can you associate a button event click with the enter key press?

Answer (score 0):

This code can handle enter keypress on page:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
   // enter pressed and u can call click function
    $('.calculete_somehing').click();
   }
});
```